# How to get only the rows thats have FINALDATE to TRUE when these same CODE have other row with FINALDATE to FALSE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the SQL query through the Group By, return what is returning, but be able in cases where a CODE is repeated and there are two records of it, one with FINALDATE: TRUE and another with FINALDATE: FALSE, can NOT display the record that contains the FINALDATE: FALSE. Would this be possible? Thank you very much in advance. (I works in Oracle)

A greeting

***Query:***

```
SELECT distinct H1.CODE, ZL.DES AS ZONE, TIP.ABR, H1.ID_ITA, CASE (RS.FE_EN)
WHEN TO_DATE('10-01-2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'True'
ELSE 'False'
END AS FINALDATE
FROM SCHEMA.Fnt_Habitaciones h1 
INNER   JOIN  SCHEMA.GEN_ITA_PO  TIP   ON H1.ID_ITA_PO = TIP.ID_ITA_PO
LEFT    JOIN  SCHEMA.PIS_ITA   PZ    ON H1.ID_ITA = PZ.ID_HABITACIONES
LEFT    JOIN  SCHEMA.PIS_ZOEZA   ZL    ON ZL.ID_ZOEZA = PZ.ID_ZOEZA  AND 0 
IS NOT NULL AND 0 = 1
INNER   JOIN  SCHEMA.RES_RESERVAS       RS    ON RS.ID_ITA = H1.ID_ITA
WHERE h1.activo=1 AND h1.id_esta= 15 AND (48 IS NULL OR 48 IS NOT NULL AND 
H1.ID_BLOQUES = 48)
AND h1.id_ita NOT IN 
( 
 SELECT hin.id_ita 
 FROM SCHEMA.Res_Reservas r 
 INNER JOIN SCHEMA.Fnt_ita hin ON hin.id_ita = r.id_ita 
 WHERE r.id_establecimientos = hin.id_establecimientos AND 
 hin.id_establecimientos = 15 AND r.id_ita IS NOT NULL 
 AND (('10-01-2018' > r.FE_EN AND '10-01-2018' <= r.fecha_salida ) OR ('10-
 01-2018' < r.FE_EN AND '10-01-2018' >= r.fecha_salida)) 
) AND h1.id_ita NOT IN 
  (   
   SELECT hbin.id_ita FROM SCHEMA.Fnt_BloHab b 
   INNER JOIN SCHEMA.Fnt_ita hbin ON hbin.id_ita = b.id_ita 
   WHERE b.activo=1 AND '10-01-2018' >= b.fecha_inicio AND '10-01-2018' <= 
   b.fecha_fin AND b.indHouKee = 1
  )
GROUP BY ZL.DES, H1.CODE, TIP.ABR,H1.ID_ita, RS.FE_EN
ORDER BY ZL.DES, h1.CODE ASC;
```

***Result:***

```
CODE     ZONE       ABR  ID_ITA FINALDATE   

0123    (null)      DFAP 3349   False
1013    (null)      DST  3257   False
1105    (null)      DFA  3373   False --> I want this will nop appear in result. Because we have a TRUE with this CODE.
1105    (null)      DFA  3373   True
2105    (null)      DST  3541   False
3019    (null)      DSTV 3644   False
4001    (null)      SES  3798   False
4003    (null)      SES  3799   False
4005    (null)      SES  3800   False
4011    (null)      DSU  3803   True
4011    (null)      DSU  3803   False --> I want this will nop appear in result. Because we have a TRUE with this CODE.
4025    (null)      JUS  3813   False
```

***THANKS!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could just use aggregation, which relies on the alphabetic sorting of 'False' before 'True':

```
SELECT H1.CODE, ZL.DES AS ZONE, TIP.ABR, H1.ID_ITA,
  MAX(
    CASE RS.FE_EN 
      WHEN TO_DATE('10-01-2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'True'
      ELSE 'False'
    END
  ) AS FINALDATE
...
GROUP BY ZL.DES, H1.CODE, TIP.ABR, H1.ID_ita
ORDER BY ZL.DES, h1.CODE ASC;
```

The specific `RS.FE_EN` is removed from the group-by clause as that's now only referenced inside the aggregate `max()` function call.

---

As a side issue, you seem to be relying on implicit conversions and your session's NLS settings for things like

```
'10-01-2018' > r.FE_EN AND '10-01-2018' <= r.fecha_salida
```

It would be better to explicitly convert strings to dates, as you are in the case expression; or use date literals:

```
DATE '2018-01-10' > r.FE_EN AND DATE '2018-01-10' <= r.fecha_salida
```

etc.; you can use that in the case expression as well instead of `to_date()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, doing what you said, does exactly what I needed! THAAAAANKS!!